# Ubuntu 12.10 does not scan for new wireless after disconnect

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking

New Ubuntu 12.10 install on a Samsung NP700Z5C-S01UB Series 7 Laptop - 15.6" works great. But when the wireless disconnects (due to moving around), the machine will not scan for new networks unless rebooted? I can check and uncheck wireless on the bug but it will not scan for networks unless rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the connection to re-connect? 
Here is how....

- Go to the network manager icon (the wireless icon) and click 'edit connection'
- Click on the wireless tab and pick the connection you are using then click 'edit'
- Be sure 'Connect automaticly' is checked
- If the network is not an open one, click on the 'wireless security' tab and enter the security type and key.
- Make sure the 'Available to all users' is checked in the lower left.

Comment: Yes reconnects work fine, but nothing triggers a scan other than a reboot so if I go to a coffee shop in hibernate, I wake up and need to reboot. to get a scan in a new location. The results of the scan persist 'till the next reboot.

Comment: I had assumed your connection was just dropping. There appears to be a bug with some people re-connecting from sleep/hibernation. I have located a potential fix. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/274405/comments/74